Database Connection using OAuth2 Token
I am working on a Spring Boot project where I need to connect to Snowflake db using OAuth2 token which expires in every 10 min.
Does Spring Boot has any simple approach to achieve the same ?
My Approach:
I've made a custom class that extends HikariDataSource and managing connection and creating new connection every time token expire.
public class SnowflakeDataSource extends HikariDataSource {
    private SnowflakeDataSource dataSource;
    private HikariConfig config;

    public SnowflakeDataSource(HikariConfig config) {
        super(config);
        this.config = config;
        this.dataSource = this;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (isTokenExpired()) {
            this.config.getDataSourceProperties().put("token", generateNewToken());
            dataSource.getHikariPoolMXBean().softEvictConnections();
            this.dataSource = new SnowflakeDataSource(config);
        }
        return this.dataSource.getSuperConnection();
    }

    private Connection getSuperConnection() {
        return super.getConnection();
    }
}


The custom oauth client mechanism for Snowflake gives the option to have the oauth token lifetime defined as per requirement.
OAUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY = 86400
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-custom#integration-example

Hi @SrinathMenon, thanks but even if the validity changes to 86400, my server still has to refresh it after 1 day.

@ParthaSarathi just wondering what is the drawback with your approach. it seems simple enough.

@Imran, no as such issue, it's working just fine. just seeking expert advices if there can be any potential issue with it. And if there any simple solution to the same, because i couldn't find one.

Wouldn't it be just easier to set the max live time to something smaller then the token lifetime. Create an additional process that only refreshes the token. That would require only a token reset and no extension of the HikariDataSource meaning you can still rely on the auto configuration of Spring Boot.

@M.Deinum, thanks for the suggestion, could you elaborate a little more about additional process to refresh the token ?

That could just be a scheduled task that checks and updates the token in the HikariDatasource. Basically the same you have now but with an @Scheduled and it would just be a regular class no need to extend the HikariDataSource bits.

Understood. So basically max live time will close the current connection, and in the mean time, Scheduled task will update token in my config, which will be taken into consideration next time the connection established. Great.

@M.Deinum, Just a point, in that case, my Scheduled task will keep running every 10 min, even if I don't need it, for example let's say nobody uses the application during night or Sunday, then also the Scheduled task will keep running unnecessarily. In that case my approach will only refresh the token only when I'm trying to get the connection to execute some query.

@ParthaSarathi The reason why the token lifetime is set to a lower value is to ensure that it does not get used by unauthorized resources / actors. And the token refresh will need to be done from the application side based on that and I don't think there is any other means to not do it. Even if available, I would not suggest taking that route from a security perspective.
